# Last inherited display property is inline but computed is block. How is this even possible?

Tags: css, firebug

I am styling an `<input type="text">` element. **I would like to let it have `display:inline;`**. I did this by targeting this element in the last line of the css file that is called last. For some reason the element doesn't take over the `display:inline;` property (see Firebug image below).

How is it even possible?

[image: Firebug pic]

Comment: try `!important` yet `display:inline !important;`

Comment: @Stano: It reports the same thing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because your `input` element is floated left, the computed value of display is set to block according to the CSS specification.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

**Comment**

I would not expect that using the `!important` declaration would over ride the computed value.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and for including the reference! Indeed, `!important` did not override anything.

Answer (score 2):

I had this structure:

```
<div class="parent">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <label>Some awesome label</label>
</div>
```

`div.parent` was set as `display: flex` and it caused `input` and `label` to inherit `display: block`. It took me while to find the cause but changing that the parent div to `display: block` resolved the situation.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, you saved me 2 hours of existential css questioning